# Send a dynamic message at runtime to an object in Objective-c on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, action, message

Is it possible to craft a message at runtime and send it to an object in objective-c on iOS?
Let's say I have an instance of class 
`Foo` 
I want to be able to use something like

```
NSString * d = @"action1:";
[myFoo d]; 
d = @"action2:";
[myFoo d];
```

and `Foo` has at least two instant methods:

```
-(void) action1:(id)sender;
-(void) action2:(id)sender;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSString *d = @"action1:";
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(d);
if ([myFoo respondsToSelector:selector])
{
    [myFoo performSelector:selector withObject:someObject];
}
```

There are a number of different `performSelector` methods on `NSObject`. You can call with no params, with delays, etc.

Comment: For more complex methods, use `objc_msgSend(myFoo, selector, args)`. Depending on the type of the arguments and the return type of the method, you should cast `&objc_msgSend` to the appropriate function pointer type before calling it.

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks for the comment, it happend that I need to call more complex methods as well as simple ons (@typeoneerror 's answer works just fine). Why `objc_msgSend` returns an id, when it already sends the message?

Comment: `objc_msgSend` actually returns the return value of the method named by the selector. By default, Objective-C methods return an `id`, so the return type of `objc_msgSend` matches. However, for any other return type you *must* cast `objc_msgSend()` or you enter into undefined behaviour territory. (Experts know the wiggle room associated with that statement, but better to code strictly now, before you're an expert in the language.)